# Remove last digit of binary data type for select and searches

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I want to search for values define in a defined range inside a column with `binary` type.
Consider it is binary(3). So I got values such as:

```
0x000123
0x000124
0x000135
0x000136
```

I want to select values which their first 5 hex digits start from '00001' up to '00012'. I mean I want to search only in 5 out of 6 hexadecimal digit values stored in binary(3).

I used `substring` function like this:

```
select substring(binaryColumn,1,2)) from myTable
```

or

```
select substring(binaryColumn,1,3)) from myTable
```

but it trims the text by defined bytes not their hex digits as below:

```
0x0001
0x0001
0x0001
0x0001
```

and

```
0x000123
0x000124
0x000135
0x000136
```

How can I get the only 5 digits and search in a defined range considering only first 5 hex digits?

**P.S.** Consider that efficiency of query is one of my main concerns.

Comment: Well converting your binary column value to a string for searching is definitely going to perform badly. Why not search as a binary e.g. `where MyColumn >= 0x00001 and MyColumn <= 0x00012`?

Comment: Otherwise check out the documentation for `convert` it shows you how to ignore the "0x".

Comment: Binary data is, well, binary. It's not its hexadecimal representation...